# Delete specific symbol and number at the end of filename if exist

Tags: vb.net

My application is downloading many diffrent files from network. There is possibility that some of the files could contain additional number within brackets like below:

```
 report78-12-34-34_ex                                  'nothing to be removed 
 blabla3424dm_d334(7)                                  '(7) - to be removed
 erer3r3r3_2015_03_03-1945-user-_d334(31).xml          '(31) - to be removed 
 group78-12-34-34_ex.html                              'nothing to be removed
 somereport5_6456                                       'nothing to be removed
```

As you see if (number) appear within filename it has to be removed. Do you have some nice secure method which could do the job?

I got some code from rakesh but it is not working when string doesn't contain (number):

```
string test="something(3)";
test=Regex.Replace(test, @"\d", "").Replace("()","");
```

Not working when e.g:

if i place file like this: `UIPArt3MilaGroupUIAPO34mev1-mihe-2015_9_23-21_30_5_580.csv` then it will show: `UIPArtMilaGroupUIAPOmev-mihe--_.csv`

And i would prefer not using regex.

Comment: You can use Regex for this

Comment: see my post i have regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoids Regex and checks the string inside the parentheses, only removing the substring if the enclosed string is a number.

```
Private Function NewFileName(ByVal FileName As String) As String
    If FileName Like "*(*)*" Then
        Try
            Dim SubStrings() As String = Split(FileName, "(", 2)
            NewFileName = SubStrings(0)
            SubStrings = Split(SubStrings(1), ")", 2)
            SubStrings(0) = NewFileName(SubStrings(0))
            SubStrings(1) = NewFileName(SubStrings(1))
            If IsNumeric(SubStrings(0)) Then
                NewFileName &= SubStrings(1)
            Else
                Return FileName
            End If
        Catch
            Return FileName
        End Try
    Else
        Return FileName
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to be ok i checked various scenarios. What could be the situation it would not work? For instance more bracets lets say additional opening racet at the beggining then probably not work.

Comment: @StackUser, yes, there are possible strings that would not be caught by this function. As written, it tests the string between the first "(" and the first ")" following it. So "employeeFile(Smith)Backup(7)" would not process correctly because "Smith" is not numeric.

Comment: @StackUser, I just corrected the above with a little recursion. However, filenames with nested parentheses will still fail the test, e.g. "Pennington Labs(VirginiaAuthorizationForm(32))" or "ContractUpdate((27))"

Comment: so there is nothing we can do in this case. Can we add feature that if two or more brackets occur rather than one then just return oryginal filename?

Comment: @StackUser, that's what the function as previously written already did. However, I just added a second recursive branch that should fix the problem. (I don't naturally think recursively, so neither of the recursive edits occurred to me originally.) I can't think of a case that will fail this version.

Comment: @StackUser, actually, ignore my last edit. I left it for you to see, but it won't work. (It's still looking at the first open/close parenthesis, so nesting will still return the original filename.) If you need it to alter strings with nested parentheses it will take a complete rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
Public Function GetFileName(ByVal fileName As String) As String

    Dim lastOpenBracketPos As Integer = fileName.LastIndexOf("(")
    Dim lastCloseBracketPos As Integer = fileName.LastIndexOf(")")
    If lastOpenBracketPos <> -1 AndAlso lastCloseBracketPos <> -1 AndAlso lastCloseBracketPos > lastOpenBracketPos Then
        Dim bracketsText As String = fileName.Substring(lastOpenBracketPos, lastCloseBracketPos-lastOpenBracketPos+1)
        If IsNumeric(bracketsText.Trim("(",")")) Then
            Return fileName.Replace(bracketsText,"")
        End If
    End If
    Return fileName

End Function
```

Comment: hmm... that would change the function. I've updated it to take into account this new possible filename.

Answer (score 0):

Out of all code here i made out my own one because it has to be ensured that before every playing with filename first has to be checked how many brackets within filename - only if 1 for open and 1 for close bracket is there then go with checking. What do you think is there any issue i don;t see or something which could be tuned up?

```
Private Function DeleteBrackets(ByVal fn As String) As String

        Dim countOpenBracket As Integer = fn.Split("(").Length - 1
        Dim countCloseBracket As Integer = fn.Split(")").Length - 1

        '-- If only one occurence of ( and one occurence of )
        If countOpenBracket = 1 And countCloseBracket = 1 Then

            Dim filextension = IO.Path.GetExtension(fn)
            Dim filewithoutExtension As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn)

            'Debug.Print("Oryginal file name = " & fn)
            'Debug.Print("File name without extension = " & filewithoutExtension)
            'Debug.Print("Extension = " & IO.Path.GetExtension(fn))

            If filewithoutExtension.EndsWith(")") Then
                fn = filewithoutExtension.Remove(filewithoutExtension.LastIndexOf("("))
                'Debug.Print("After removing last index of ( = " & fn)
                'Debug.Print("Adding again extension = " & fn & filextension)
            End If

            'Debug.Print(fn)
        End If

        Return fn

    End Function
```